# How to connect MongoDB with SharePoint List?

Tags: mongodb, sharepoint, office365

I have a MongoDB data base with some missing fields. I want to create a SharePoint list that will get full data from MongoDB. Then the users will be able to fill the missing data using Sharepoint list.

If the data is updated by the user in the SharePoint list, I want it to be updated in MongoDB too - thus all missing data in the database will eventually be added.

How can I achieve this? How can I connect MongoDB with Sharepoint?